# Error in command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So this is fairly complicated. I am making a sign, that when clicked, will give you a book, that when you click the text will execute a give command:

```
/blockdata ~ ~ ~-1 { Text1: "{ text:\"[Click For Book]\", color:dark_blue,clickEvent: { action:run_command, value:{"command":"/give @p written_book 1 0 {pages:%s,title:Book,author:Shop}","jobject":[{"text":"Click For 1 Gold","color":"gold","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/scoreboard players add @p Gold 1"}},{"text":"     --------------                                                          "},{"text":"Click For 5 Gold","color":"gold","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/scoreboard players add @p Gold 5"}},{"text":"     --------------                                                          "},{"text":"Click For 10 Gold","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/scoreboard players add @p Gold 10"}}],"jtemplate":"book"} }}"}
```

However when I execute this command it gives me:

```
[17:10:33] Data tag parsing failed: Unexpected token 'c' at: command":"/give @p written_book 1 0 {pages:%s,title:Book,author:Shop}","jobject":[{"text":"Click For 1 Gold","color":"gold","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/scoreboard players add @p Gold 1"}},{"text":"     --------------                                                          "},{"text":"Click For 5 Gold","color":"gold","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/scoreboard players add @p Gold 5"}},{"text":"     --------------                                                          "},{"text":"Click For 10 Gold","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/scoreboard players add @p Gold 10"}}],"jtemplate":"book"} }}"
```

I do not understand why I am getting this error, can someone who is good at command proof-scan the command to make sure there are no errors? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you've either got an extra "c" or a missing character. Maybe a bracket? Either that or code is just wrong in that area.

Comment: @FezodgeIII It is complaining about the "c" in command, not an extra one,  and no, I do not have any extra or missing brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't escape any of the quotation marks in any of the string fields except for the `text:\"[Click For Book]\"` part.

If you want everything to be part of the `Text1` string, then every time you write `"`, you should instead write `\"`, **except for the first and last instance**. You have already done this in the part I mentioned, you just have to do it in the rest of the command.

Answer (score -2):

Try this. It works in 1.8

```
/setblock x y z wall_sign 0 replace {Text1:"{text:\"Click for book\",color:color,clickEvent:{action:run_command,value:\"/give @p book\"}}",Text2:"{text:\"\",color:color}",Text3:"{text:\"\",color:color}",Text4:"{text:\"\",color:color}"}
```

Don't mind the text 2-4 coz I just copied this from my Notepad.